# Monitor network traffic over CentOS router

Tags: centos, bandwidth, router

I have a CentOS 5.7 box configured as a router. Two network cards are attached to this machine, one connected to the Internet and one connected to an **unmanaged** network switch.

The question is, how can I monitor bandwidth usage per IP address routed through this machine. 
I know how to monitor instant traffic and ports, I want to monitor the -- for example daily, monthly traffic.

any help is appreciated.

A

Answer (score 0):

NTOP should be able to give you these statistics, as well as a nice per-protocol breakdown. If your router doesn't have a lot of memory or processing, I would recommend looking into mirroring the traffic to another machine and running NTOP on there.